# Description of Lord Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, symbolism, symbols

I've read in slokams and places where it is mentioned that Lord Srinivas/Vishnu adorns Kausthubham and wears Peethambaram.

I searched in Google but unable to find what it actually means?

Can someone tell me what does it mean by

1. Kausthubham
2. Srivatsam
3. Peerthambaram

It would be really beneficial if someone could name all the important ornaments of Lord Vishnu and his consorts on his chest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Peetambar & Kautubh Mani**

> The lord, appearing on the shoulder of Garuda, seemed like a cloud resting on the summit of the mountain known as Meru. The body of the lord was covered by attractive **yellow garments (peetambar)**, and His neck was decorated with the jewel known as **Kaustubha-mani**. The bodily effulgence of the Lord dissipated all the darkness of the universe.” (Shrimad Bhagavatam, 4.30.5)

Thus Yellow garments mean Peetambar(peet-yellow, Ambar-clothes)

Kaustubh was the 4th gem which came from Sagar Manthana. And devas offered it to Shree Hari.

**Srī Vatsā cinhā**

Srī Vatsā cinhā is the mark on right side of chest of Shri Hari. Where devi Laxmi resides. Every vigraha of Vishnu has it. For more read [Here](https://www.sanatan.org/en/a/101985.html)

[image]

The cinhā is marked, as you see.

```
could name all the important ornaments of Lord Vishnu and his consorts on his chest.
```

Every Vigraha has different Abharan and Asbhushans. Will explain abt, Balaji and Vitthal here.

**Venkateshwara, Tirumala**

[image]

One ornament missing here is **Vajra Kavach**, which is bedecked on his chest.
The Mukhut on his head is known as **Vajra kirita**.
**Vaijanthi mala** is his favourite garland thus adorned with it.
**Surya Katari** is the sword of Venkateshwara.
**Makar Kundala** (Makar shaped) are one type of earrings mentioned for male deities in Agams.

After the vigraha is done with alankaram, **Laxmi and Padmavati** are adorned on the chest of Venkateshwara. Thus giving the true name to the lord, **Shree Nivas**.(The place where Laxmi resides)

[image]

**Devi Laxmi on left side and Padmavati on right side of the chest**.

**Vitthal, Pandharpur**

[image]

The ear rings here are **Matsyakundal**(fish shaped).
Between the feets of Vitthal is a **stick with Bells**(ghunghru).
Mukhut which looks like a hat, but is called **Shivling**.
A 3 roped waist band called **Mekhala**.
Some common features -
2 kadas(Bajuband) on arms, Kaustubh Mani on chest, Srī Vatsā Cinhā on right side of chest, Lotus in right hand, and conch in left, and the lord is standing on Brick (in marathi brick is called as Vith, thus the name Vitthal)

Hope rest is vivid here.

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Comment: Is Srivatsam mark, a type of mole as in humans? Or how to understand the Srivatsam mark on the Lord?

Comment: @Newbie nope it's not mole. It's the white patch present in the most sacred pattern. https://www.sanatan.org/en/a/101985.html   read this

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. The Kaustubh and the Srivatsam Mark on Vishnu

> Chapter 22, Book 1, Vishnu Purana
>
> श्रीपराशर उवाच
>
> नमस्कृत्वाप्रमेयाय विष्णवे प्रभविष्णवे । कथयामि यथाख्यातं वसिष्ठेन ममा
> भवत् ॥ १,२२.६७ ॥ आत्मानमस्य जगतो निर्लेपमगुणामलम् । बिभर्ति
> कौस्तुभमणिस्वरूपं भगवान्हरिः ॥ १,२२.६८ ॥ श्रीवत्ससंस्थानधरमनन्तेन
> समाश्रितम् । प्रधानं बुद्धिरप्यास्ते गदारूपेण माधवे ॥ १,२२.६९ ॥
> भूतादिमिन्द्रियादिं च द्विधाहङ्कारमीश्वरः । बिभर्ति शंखरूपेण
> शार्ङ्गरूपेण च स्थितम् ॥ १,२२.७० ॥ चलत्स्वरूपमत्यन्तं
> जवेनान्तारितानिलम् । चक्रस्वरूपं च मनो धत्ते विष्णुकरे स्थितम् ॥
> १,२२.७१ ॥ पञ्चरूपा तु या माला वैजयन्ती गदाभृतः । सा भूतहेतुसंघाता
> भूतमाला च वै द्विज ॥ १,२२.७२ ॥ यानीन्द्रियाण्यशेषाणि
> बुद्धिकर्मात्मकानि वै । शररूपाण्यशेषाणि तानि धत्ते जनार्दनः ॥ १,२२.७३
> ॥ बिभर्ति यच्चासिरत्नमच्युतोत्यन्तनिर्मलम् । विद्यामय तु
> तज्ज्ञानमविद्याकोशसंस्थितम् ॥ १,२२.७४ ॥ इत्थं पुमान्प्रधानं च
> बुद्ध्यहङ्कारमेव च । भूतानि च हृषीकेशे मनः सर्वेन्द्रियाणि च ।
> विद्याविद्ये च मैत्रेय सर्वमेतत्समाश्रितम् ॥ १,२२.७५ ॥
> अस्त्रभूषणसंस्थानस्वरूपं रूपवर्जितः । बिभार्ति मायारूपोसौ श्रेयसे
> प्राणिनां हरिः ॥ १,२२.७६ ॥ सविकारं प्रधानं च पुमांश्चैवाखिलं जगत् ।
> बिभर्ति पुण्डहीकाक्षस्तदेवं परमेश्वरः ॥ १,२२.७७ ॥ या विद्या या
> तथाविद्या यत्सद्यच्चासदव्ययम् । तत्सर्वं सर्वभूतेशे मैत्रेय मधुसूदने ॥
> १,२२.७८ ॥ कलाकाष्ठानिमेषादिदिनर्त्वयनहायनैः । कालस्वरूपो भगवानपापो
> हरिरव्ययः ॥ १,२२.७९ ॥
>
> > Having offered salutation to the mighty and indescribable Viṣṇu, I
> > repeat to you what was formerly related to me by Vaśiṣṭha.
>
> > - **The glorious Hari wears the pure soul of the world, undefiled, and void of qualities, as the Kaustubha gem**.
>
> > - **The chief principle of things (Pradhāna) is seated on the eternal, as the Srivatsa mark.**
>
> > - **Intellect abides in Mādhava, in the form of his mace**.
>
> > - **The lord (Īśvara) supports egotism (Ahaṅkāra) in its twofold division, into elements and organs of sense, in the emblems of his
> >   conch-shell and his bow**.
>
> > - **In his hand Viṣṇu holds, in the form of his discus, the mind, whose thoughts (like the weapon) fly swifter than the winds. The
> >   necklace of the deity Vaijayantī, composed of five precious gems, is
> >   the aggregate of the five elemental rudiments. Janārddana bears, in
> >   his numerous shafts, the faculties both of action and of perception.**
>
> > - **The bright sword of Achyuta is holy wisdom, concealed at some seasons in the scabbard of ignorance.**
>
> > In this manner soul, nature, intellect, egotism, the elements, the
> > senses, mind, ignorance, and wisdom, are all assembled in the person
> > of Hṛṣikeśa. **Hari, in a delusive form, embodies the shapeless
> > elements of the world, as his weapons and his ornaments, for the
> > salvation of mankind. Puṇḍarikākṣa, the lord of all, assumes nature,
> > with all its products, soul and all the world.** All that is wisdom,
> > all that is ignorance, all that is, all that is not, all that is
> > everlasting, is centred in the destroyer of Madhu, the lord of all
> > creatures. The supreme, eternal Hari is time, with its divisions of
> > seconds, minutes, days, months, seasons, and years.

So, Kaustubh gem is a representation of the Soul and its divinity, while Srivatsa mark is a symbolism for the Pradhana, all of which are under the Lord's control.

---

#### 2. Yellow robes of Vishnu

> [SriMatham: Vaiṣṇava Iconology based on Pañcarātra Āgama](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/icon_of_panc_1.pdf)
>
> **The Yellow Robe (pitāmbara):—Yellow which is the colour of the fire
> represents yajña or Sacrifice which is the principle activity taught
> in the Vedas.** The Lord is known as yajña-puruṣa the One who receives
> all the oblations offered into the sacred fire. The act of creation is
> depicte d in the Vedas as a cosmic sacrifice in which the Supreme
> Person Himself becomes the victim, and it is from this primeval
> sacrifice that the cosmos has its origins. **The yellow robe symbolizes
> fire and the principle of sacrifice which underlies all human
> transactions with the environment and with other beings.** In order to
> receive we must give, obtaining one thing also requires letting go of
> another. This ethically managed reciprocity is the foundation of
> Dharma practice.

Even the Srimada Bhagvatam states the significance.

> Srimada Bhagvatam Mahapurana [12.11.11](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/11/11-12/)
>
> वासश्छन्दोमयं पीतं
>
> > **The yellow robe or garments of the Lord represents the metres of the Vedas.**